Vite React SSG Redirection
I am trying to make my website redirect to a 404 page when the path is not set, using vite-react-ssg and react-router-dom. I need to use SSG because of pre-rendering.
I can't find any documentation on how to do this. vite-react-ssg
Has anyone tried it?
Is it possible to do so?
I try something like this, but it didn't work:
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    Component: Layout,
    children: [
      {
        path: '404',
        Component: lazy(() => import('@components/NotFound')),
      },
      {
        path: '*',
        redirect: '404',
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
]

I need examples or documentation on how to redirect an unconfigured route in react using vite-react-ssg pre-rendering.

What you have shown only works if user navigates to "/404" on the client. Is this what you are trying to accomplish? Or are you instead trying to implement some server-side rewrite/redirect to this page if the client requests a page that doesn't exist?

I was trying that if for example it enters the path /no-configured it redirects it to the path /404, but it didn't work.

I think instead of redirect: '404', you use element: <Navigate to="/404" replace />, to render a redirect to the target route path. redirect doesn't appear to be any prop the Route component uses/recognizes. If this is what you are looking for I can write up an answer/explanation.

@DrewReese Yessssss, it worked. Don't forget to comment that it needs to be imported as well.


I was trying that if for example it enters the path "/no-configured" it
redirects it to the path "/404", but it didn't work.

What you have shown only works if user navigates to "/404" on the client directly. If you are wanting to define a "catch-all" route that redirects to this 404 path/page then import and use the Navigate component from react-router-dom and render a redirect.
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    Component: Layout,
    children: [
      {
        path: '404',
        Component: lazy(() => import('@components/NotFound')),
      },
      {
        path: '*',
        element: <Navigate to="/404" replace />,
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
]

FWIW redirect isn't a recognized Route component prop. See Type Declaration (or view source code for what vite-react-ssg imports from react-router-dom).

interface RouteObject {
  path?: string;
  index?: boolean;
  children?: RouteObject[];
  caseSensitive?: boolean;
  id?: string;
  loader?: LoaderFunction;
  action?: ActionFunction;
  element?: React.ReactNode | null;
  hydrateFallbackElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
  errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
  Component?: React.ComponentType | null;
  HydrateFallback?: React.ComponentType | null;
  ErrorBoundary?: React.ComponentType | null;
  handle?: RouteObject["handle"];
  shouldRevalidate?: ShouldRevalidateFunction;
  lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<RouteObject>;
}


